# How can I "force" pgfplotstable to be under a heading

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

Due to a recommendation on this board, I have decided to use pgfplotstable in my lab reports to import data from a CSV and print it out as a table in LaTeX. However, in a section such as my appendices, I need tables to be under headings (not above them), so how can I force LaTeX to place the table where I put it in my code.

Sample:

```
\appendix
\appendixpage
\section{Tables}
\begin{subappendices}
\subsection{Heading 1}
\pgfplotstableread{mydata.csv}{\mydatalabel}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption[LoT Caption]{Full Caption}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
        every head row/.style={
            before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={
            after row=\bottomrule},
        ]{\mydatalabel}
    \label{table:mydatalabel}
\end{table}
```

LaTeX will do its automatic formatting and place my tables above Heading 1 (and other headings too).

Before the use of pgfplotstables, I used this code for my tables to force them where they are meant to be:

```
\begin{center}
    \captionof{table}[LoT Caption]{Full Caption}        
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
        \toprule

        \bottomrule
        \label{table:mydatalabel} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Is there something similar I can do? I really like using pgfplotstables so far since I don't have to manually enter data into tables anymore

Comment: Did you try it? I don't have your data file, so I can't test, but as far as I know, nothing is preventing you from replacing `\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}` with `\pgfplotstabletypeset[...]{...}` in your last code snippet. The `\label{}` does _not_ need to be inside the `tabular` environment: as long as it comes after `\caption` it's fine.

Comment: It is nothing to do with pgfplots table, just the behavoiour of the `table` environment see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Nothing requires `\pgfplotstabletypeset` to be used inside of a `table` environment; it can be used anywhere a `tabular` environment might be used.

You may be hung up on the `\label` command appearing inside the `tabular` environment in your last code snippet. There's no requirement for this, either. As long as the `\label` comes *after* the `\caption`, it will work as expected.

So here is how it could be done. I used the example data file from the `pgfplotstable` manual since I do not have access to your data file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
Table~\ref{table:mydata} is typeset just fine by \verb|pgfplotstable|,
even outside of a \verb|table| environment.
\begin{center}
  \captionof{table}[Short Caption]{This is the full, long-form caption.}
  \label{table:mydata}
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={dof,error1}]{pgfplotstable.example1.dat}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]